# generate user_data including "IP Address" while creating ec2 instance using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, user-data, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to spin 2 `ec2` instances using `terraform`. Something like this

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count                       = "${var.number_of_instances}"
  ami                         = "${var.ami_name}"
  associate_public_ip_address = "${var.associate_public_ip_address}"
  instance_type               = "${var.instance_type}"
  key_name                    = "${var.keyname}"
  subnet_id                   = "${element(var.subnet_ids, count.index)}"
  user_data                   = "${element(data.template_file.example.*.rendered, count.index)}"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = ["${aws_security_group.example.id}","${var.extra_security_group_id}"]
  root_block_device {
    volume_size = "${var.root_volume_size}"
    volume_type = "${var.root_volume_type}"
    iops        = "${var.root_volume_iops}"
  }
  tags {
    Name      = "${var.prefix}${var.name}${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  }
}
```

In `template_file` all I am trying to do is to generate a config file with `IP Address` of both the instances using `user_data` but this fails saying `Cycle Error`.

Is there any way to get the file to generate with `IP Address` while the `ec2` instances are coming up

Comment: Show us the template_file code

Comment: What you have here is a "chicken or egg" problem: user_data must be fixed when the instance is first created, and at that point the instance doesn't have an IP address yet (unless you assign it a static one). To solve this, you'll need to introduce something new. For example, you could create some DNS records at a predictable name which your instances can then read to find one another after boot, though you'd need to design it to be resilient to there being a delay after the instance is created before the DNS record becomes available.

Comment: @MartinAtkins I actually thought about it and tried the external `DNSName` thing. But I have some stupid logic here in my company where Security won't allow connecting to external `DNSName` on a `port` anything else `443`.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the [AWS Instance Metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval) in your userdata script to get each instance's IP address and put it into a config file. Here is a Powershell example of a userdata script:

```
<powershell>
$HostIp = (Invoke-RestMethod -URI 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4' -UseBasicParsing)
Add-Content "C:\installer\config.txt" "HostIp:$HostIp"
</powershell>
```

You can also get the instance's `public-ipv4` in this manner if that's desired instead.

Answer (score 0):

By combining the various information, you can use `user_data` argument of the `resource "aws_launch_template"` block, to call a shell, itself may call in return a typical special metadata endpoint. For the private IP, it would be:
`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`